# Cannot find an index in the referenced table. Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

When I am trying to create foreign key I have the message : "cannot add foreign key.." 
In the engine innodb status I have this next statement :

[Innodb Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuQGY.png)
[image: Innodb Error]

I checked the collation and type and no found :

[Full columns tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUdvG.png)
[image: Full columns tables]

Indeed,

I have 2 foreign key in my "supportCoursGen" table. For the first foreign key I am doing this :

```
ALTER TABLE supportCoursGen 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_supportCoursGen_supCoursSource
     FOREIGN KEY (idSupportCoursSource) REFERENCES supportCoursSource(id);
```

It work.

But with this "code" :

```
alter table supportCoursGen
add constraint fk_supportCoursGen_codeBaps
        foreign key (libCodeBaps) references codeBaps (libCodeBaps);
```

Doesn't Work at all.

Comment: There is no index by `libCodeBaps` field (alone or as a prefix) in `codeBaps` table...

Comment: Ok I create this index and it work but I realise that when I did not references to a primary key I need to create an index to the references tables.

Comment: How can you reference with a foreign key, a non unique column ?

Comment: *when I did not references to a primary key I need to create an index* EACH reference NEEDS in index. Primary key is an index itself. First. Unique. With NOT NULL expression. Maybe clustered. But primarily - index.

Comment: Yes sure... Thats obvious @Gosfly

Comment: @Gosfly . . . Actually, MySQL does allow that, although I would strongly discourage anyone from ever using that functionality.